# sudo netstat -antp not showing PID

Tags: socket, netstat, unix-sockets

i am testing stuff with sockets and i encountered that strange case :

i coded i very simple tcp server in c, i made it block after accept(), just to see what happen when accepting multiple connection attempts at the same time :

Here is an excerpt of code of the server :

```
//listen()
if( (listen(sock,5)) == -1) {
  perror("listen");
  exit(-1);
}

//accept()
if( (cli = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &len)) == 1 ){
  perror("accept");
  exit(-1);
}

printf("entrez un int : ");
scanf("%d",&toto);
```

when the server asks the user to enter an integer, i try to connect multiple clients with telnet.

Fort the first one, evrything is ok :

```
root@[...] :/home/[...]/workspace/sockets# netstat -antp | grep 10003
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10003           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25832/toto      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10003         127.0.0.1:51166         ESTABLISHED 25832/toto      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51166         127.0.0.1:10003         ESTABLISHED 25845/telnet
```

but then after the first one, even though i am root, there are some connections i can't see the process owning it and its pid :

```
root@[...] :/home/[...]/workspace/sockets# netstat -antp | grep 10003
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10003           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25832/toto      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10003         127.0.0.1:51166         ESTABLISHED 25832/toto      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51166         127.0.0.1:10003         ESTABLISHED 25845/telnet    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10003         127.0.0.1:51168         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51168         127.0.0.1:10003         ESTABLISHED 25852/telnet
```

a third one :

```
root@[...] :/home/[...]/workspace/sockets# netstat -antp | grep 10003
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10003           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25832/toto      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10003         127.0.0.1:51166         ESTABLISHED 25832/toto      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51166         127.0.0.1:10003         ESTABLISHED 25845/telnet    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10003         127.0.0.1:51172         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10003         127.0.0.1:51168         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51168         127.0.0.1:10003         ESTABLISHED 25852/telnet    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51172         127.0.0.1:10003         ESTABLISHED 25860/telnet
```

I tried again a few days later with netstat -antpe as root and here is what i got :

```
root@[...] :/home/[...]/workspace/sockets# netstat -antpe | grep 10003
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10003           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       327680      22399/toto      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33286         127.0.0.1:10003         ESTABLISHED 1000       417202      22884/telnet    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10003         127.0.0.1:33046         ESTABLISHED 0          0           -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10003         127.0.0.1:33286         ESTABLISHED 0          0           -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33044         127.0.0.1:10003         ESTABLISHED 1000       332810      22402/telnet    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33046         127.0.0.1:10003         ESTABLISHED 1000       331200      22410/telnet    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10003         127.0.0.1:33044         ESTABLISHED 1000       332801      22399/toto
```

how comes a process or a connection can have an inode of 0 ? Can someone explain me what is going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server code calls `accept()` only once. Thus, only the first connection attempt is effectively accepted and the remaining client connections are kept on a connection request queue which lives in the kernel space. The next client connection will be retrieved from the queue when `accept()` is called again.

No process owns client connections while they remain in kernel space,  because multiple processes or threads may legally accept connections from an unique pair of address and port if they enable `SO_REUSEPORT` option on all participating socket descriptors.

You can test the `SO_REUSEPORT` option by yourself by adding the following code snippet before the `bind()` call and running more than one server. You will figure that the kernel will distribute requests among them.

```
{
    int enabled = -1;
    if (setsockopt (sockd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT,
        (void*) &enabled, sizeof (enabled)) < 0) {
        perror ("setsockopt");
    }
}
```

---

Reference from `man 2 accept`:

> The *accept(sockfd)* system call is used with connection-based socket types (SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_SEQPACKET).  It extracts the first connection request on the queue of pending connections for the listening socket, *sockfd*, creates a new connected socket, and returns a new file descriptor referring to that socket.  The newly created socket is not in the listening state.  The original socket *sockfd* is unaffected by this call.

Reference from `man 7 socket`:

> SO_REUSEPORT (since Linux 3.9)
>
> Permits  multiple  AF_INET or AF_INET6 sockets to be bound to an identical socket address.  This option must be set on each socket (including the first socket) prior to calling *bind(2)* on the socket. To prevent port hijacking, all of the processes binding to the same address must have the same effective UID.  This option can be employed with both TCP and UDP sockets.
>
> For TCP sockets, this option allows *accept(2)* load distribution in a multi-threaded server to be improved by using a distinct listener socket for each thread.  This provides improved load distribution as compared to traditional techniques such using a single accept(2)ing thread that distributes connections, or having multiple threads that compete to *accept(2)* from the same socket.
>
> For UDP sockets, the use of this option can provide better distribution of incoming datagrams to multiple processes (or threads) as compared to the traditional technique of having multiple processes compete to receive datagrams on the same socket.